# Get records as of today or up to a certain date in Oracle

Tags: sql, database, oracle

Could somebody recommend the query to retrieve records up to today or certain dates?

I'm required to produce an Oracle report where user needs to enter a date and records up to that date will be shown.

I tried

```
select * from the_table where the_date <= sysdate
```

However it seems to produce an inaccurate result. What is the better query for this. For now I'm just playing around with sysdate. Later I will need to use a certain date keyed in by the user and all the records up to that date needs to be shown.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Can you explain what the "inaccurate result" is?  It would be helpful, for example, to post some examples of the data in the table, explain what rows you do and do not want to retrieve, and show where the current query is not giving those results.

Comment: When editing your post include the definition of the table you're working with - field names and datatypes, please. Are there any triggers on this table? Any constraints, default values, etc? How about indexes?  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes you get inaccurate records because of little differences like minutes and seconds when two dates have the same day/month/year. Try the following

```
select * from the_table where TRUNC(the_date) <= sysdate
```

The `TRUNC` removes the minute and the seconds. Sometimes you get inaccurate records without using that

Comment: TRUNC(the_date) in the WHERE clause will tilt the optimizer towards a full table scan, unless there's a function-based index in place.